# Pellet of lithium in a vacuum

Tags: states-of-matter

What would happen to a grain of sand sized pellet of lithium in a vacuum? Because there is no pressure, would it become more like a sticky liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The melting point of lithium is 180°C so it wouldn't turn into a liquid unless you heated it to above this temperature.

In principle all solids have a non-zero vapour pressure, so in principle solid lithium would sublime in a vacuum. However according to Wikipedia the [vapour pressure of solid lithium is well approximated by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressures_of_the_elements_(data_page)):

$$ \log P \approx 10.673 - \frac{8310}{T} $$

and at 298K (room temperature) this gives a vapour pressure of about $2 \times 10^{-20}$ Pa, which is effectively zero. So unless you're prepared to wait a very, very long time nothing is going to happen to your grain of lithium.

Answer (score 0):

It would sublime, at a rate dependent upon the temperature of the pellet.

I don't see any reason for it to become a sticky liquid.

Comment: Ah so it would just slowly turn into a gas.